# Using objects/variables initialized inside a loop?

Tags: java, loops, initialization

I declare my objects outside of an if statement, but initialize them inside of it. Later I try and use them but it won't allow it because they haven't been initialized. The if statements are structured so that they all will execute before the objects are used, and hence the objects will be initialized guaranteed, but java doesn't allow that. Any way around this?

Comment: You should post your code

Answer (score 2):

If you know that all paths will ultimately initialize them, but the compiler doesn't, you can initialize them to `null` or `0` or `false` (as ajb helpfully reminds) -- or some other special initial value you define -- when declaring them. They then have a concrete initial value.

If the variable is still `null` (or whatever it's initial value was) by the time you use it (evidenced perhaps by an NPE in the case of an object) then you know something went wrong; you can also self-document your assumptions with asserts later.

You should post your code so we can give you better advice; the compiler is relatively smart about path analysis, although it can't, of course, handle cases that rely on external input or assumed preconditions and invariants. Still, it's always possible that you've overlooked something (perhaps an exception or unexpected condition leads to a path where the value is uninitialized - which is fine, you just have to make sure it's initialized).

Comment: @user2954714 The rules about variables needing to be initialized also applies to non-object variables with types like `int` or `double` or `boolean`.  Those can be initialized to `0` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The *only* way an object's initialization is guaranteed after a conditional expression is if there exists a branch that is always executed, such as an `else` statement, or `default` in `switch` statements.

To decompose that, take this example code:

```
String word;
String name = "Peter";
if("Peter".equals(name)) {
    word = "The Bird";
}
System.out.println(word);
```

This will fail since the compiler identifies a branch in which `word` is not initialized.

If you add an `else` clause, then the compiler will believe that `word` is initialized.

```
String word;
String name = "Peter";
if("Peter".equals(name)) {
    word = "The Bird";
} else {
    word = "Nope";
}
System.out.println(word);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java requires that a variable be initialized along all possible paths to the point of use before its value can be referenced.  Eg, if you have

```
int x;
if (a == b) {
   x = 5;
}
if (c == d) {
   x = 6;
}
int y = x;
```

In the above case the compiler cannot know that either the first or second `if` statement will be true, and so it's not certain that `x` gets assigned a value along all paths leading to the assignment to `y`.  So the compiler will disallow this (and, if the compiler didn't reject this, the "verifier" inside the JVM would).

The solution is to assign a value to the variable (maybe zero or -1 in this case, `null` for an object reference) so that it's known to have a value along all paths.

But note that you probably should not just assign a dummy value to every variable you declare, since very often the compiler message that no value is assigned can indicate a real live code bug where you've accidentally omitted assigning a value to the variable along some path.

Answer (score 0):

initialize them to null

```
Object myAwesomesauceVariableOfAwesome = null;
if(myUnbelievablyWildBoolean){
    myAwesomesauceVariableOfAwesome = getAwesomesauce();
}
doSomethingCompletelyMindBlowingWithAwesomesauce(myAwesomesauceVariableOfAwesome);
```